# C++17: Want to write `hom<(A, B), C>` to alias `std::function<C(A, B)>`

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming, c++17, std-function

This question comes from an attempt to make some code read like some mathematical notation. So I'm not trying to make things readable to a general software engineer. I'm also aware that this is more trouble than it's worth, but at this point, it's personal.

Let `hom<X, Y>` be the set of (referentially transparent) functions from a type `X` to type `Y`. I am not going for performance, so I'm happy using `std::function` under the covers.

I want to be able to write `hom<A, B>` as an alias for `std::function<B(A)>` AND `hom<(A, B), C>` as an alias for `std::function<C(A, B)>`. For single variable functions, of course the simple template alias,

```
template<typename Dom, typename Cod>
using hom = std::function<Cod(Dom)>;
```

works splendidly. The bivariate case, I realise, may be impossible. But I'll put it forth to see what the SE hive-mind can come up with. I DON'T need a general solution to multivariate functions: uni- and bi-variate cases suffice.

The goal is to be able to write structures such as

```
template <typename I, typename S, typename O>
struct MooreMachine {
  S s0;
  hom<(S, I), S> tmap;
  hom<S, O> rmap;
};
```

and function signatures such as

```
template <typename I, typename S>
auto rx_scanl(S s0, hom<(S, I), S> f)
    -> hom<rx::observable<I>, rx::observable<S>> {
```

### Attempts

My attempts with preprocessor macros, of course, run into the parsing issues with the comma and this is a case where I can't put in extra parens.

After a lot of frustration, I relaxed my requirements to allow `hom<A,B,C>` to stand in for `std::function<C(A,B)>`.

I don't like that (because it pleases nobody, it doesn't fit the math and at least `std::function` is familiar, even if it is ugly). But I was surprised to find difficulty even with the relaxed notation! I naively tried overloading the template alias to find out that this isn't allowed. I also couldn't make progress with variadic templates since the parameter packs must be the final template argument for alias templates.

My best attempt was using a helper struct:

```
template<typename...>
struct hom_impl;

template<typename Dom, typename Cod>
struct hom_impl<Dom, Cod> {
    using type = std::function<Codomain(Dom)>;
};

template<typename Dom1, typename Dom2, typename Cod>
struct hom_impl<Dom1, Dom2, Cod> {
    using type = std::function<Cod(Dom1, Dom2)>;
};

template<typename... Doms>
using hom = typename hom_impl<Doms...>::type;
```

I have no idea why, but this interferes with overload resolution. Specifically, in something like `make_cata` below, it says it can't infer the template argument `S`:

```
template <typename S>
using OPI = std::optional<std::pair<S, Input>>;

template <typename S>
using OPIAlgebra = hom<OPI<S>, S>;

template <typename S>
auto make_cata(OPIAlgebra<S> alg) -> hom<std::vector<Input>, S> {
  // ...
}
```

Any ideas would be great. As I said, the problem is personal at this point. It *feels* like something I should be able to do, and I'm just being stubborn.

Like I said, I really would like `hom<(A, B), C>` or something close (like `hom((A, B), C)` in the macro case). Though my best attempt was `hom<A, B, C>`, this isn't quite the math notation and is strange to the programmer, so it really helps nobody.

Comment: `hom<(A, B), C>` is simply not a well-formed C++ syntax; there's no path through the C++ grammar that can produce this sequence of tokens. I don't believe it can be turned into something well-formed, for any definition of `hom`, `A`, `B` or `C` (at least, if `A` and `B` are meant to be types; the syntax would work if `A` and `B` are e.g. integer constants, but then it's simply equivalent to `hom<B, C>`, no way to recover `A`).

Comment: Roughly, any template parameters to the left of `::` operator are in [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts). That's why template parameter deduction fails.

Comment: Would something like `hom<dom<A, B>, C>` work for you? I think this could be arranged.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for all of your remarks. Fighting the compiler like this gave me the impression that I am against the rock of something fundamental. Your pointer to non-deduced context explains much, which gives me some ease. (More than not being able to do something, I dislike not understanding why.) Your `hom<dom<A, B>, C>` looks like something I tried with tuples/pairs (that caused problems), so I would enjoy and accept such a solution, if it wouldn't trouble you too much.

Comment: [This is the best](https://godbolt.org/z/Tsq7rTch8) I could come up with. Like you, I ran against the fact that a) alias templates can't be partially specialized, and b) going through the helper template breaks parameter deduction. So instead of aliasing `std::function`, I'm deriving from it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks so much. It works a treat for my use cases (all my unit-tests pass after refactoring.) I know there is general advice against inheriting from STL containers, but I don't have a problem with it as I almost never do anything with virtual destructors. In the past, I've inherited from STL containers to good effect.

If you want to copy-and-paste into an answer, I'll give you the green check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, I'm posting @IgorTandetnik's solution. (If he would like to post his solution, I'll happily delete this and give the green check to him.) All credit goes to him.

```
  template <typename... Ts>
  struct Doms {};

  template <typename Dom, typename Cod>
  struct Hom : public std::function<Cod(Dom)> {
    using std::function<Cod(Dom)>::function;
  };

  template <typename Cod, typename... Ts>
  struct Hom<Doms<Ts...>, Cod>
      : public std::function<Cod(Ts...)> {
    using std::function<Cod(Ts...)>::function;
  };
```

So `Hom<A, Z> == std::function<Z(A)>` and `Hom<Doms<A₁, A₂, …>, Z> == std::function<Z(A₁, A₂, …)>`

It eschews standard advice to avoid inheriting from STL containers, but since there are no virtual destructors involved, I don't see any looming pathology here.